# r How to change order x axis labels in faceted plots using free scales and how to add a seconday axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two problems:

1. change the order of xlabels in a facetted plot.
2. I would like to add a secondary axis in the faceted plot.

```
DATA
areas <- as.data.frame(c("area A", "area A", "area A", "area A", "area A", 
            "area A", "area A",   "area A", "area A", "area B", "area B", 
            "area B", "area B", "area B", "area B", "area B", "area B", 
            "area B", "area B"))

code <- as.data.frame(c("A", "D", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "A", "B", "E", "F", "G", "E", "F", "G", "E", "H", "F", "G"))

code_sec <- as.data.frame(c("CS", "FA", "IC", "MO", "CS", "FA", "IC", "CS", "IC",  "CSIC", "ICMO", "MOFA", "CSIC", "ICMO", "MOFA", "CSIC", "FAME", "ICMO","MOFA"))

sex <- as.data.frame(c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male",   "Male",   "Male" ,  "Unk",    "Unk",    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male",   "Male",  "Male", "Unk",  "Unk", "Unk", "Unk"))

 cases <- as.data.frame(c(5,1,  8,  1,  3,  1, 11,  2,  5, 22,  5,  2, 17,  
       6, 1, 13,  1, 4, 1))

freq <- as.data.frame(c(3,  6,  6,  3,  3, 2,  5,  4,  2,  9, 13,
           9, 10,  4,  4, 11,  4,  3,  2))

names(data) <- c( "areas", "code", "code_sec","sex", "cases", "freq")
```

1. I would like the graphic with x_labels as in data$code_sec in the
   next order: CS, IC, MO, FA for the first graphic and CSIC, ICMO,
   MOFA, FAME for the second graphic. However, they appear in
   alphabetical order. I used a second code name (data$code) in the
   order I require, but I can't change the x_labels in the graphic. I
   used scale_x_discrete instead of free scales and worked, but all the
   x_labels appear in both faceted graphics with blank spaces.
2. I would like to add a secondary axis with data$freq in both
   graphics, I tried to add the secondary axis in combination with the
   faceted y_free scale or with scale_y_continuos, but did not work, I
   did not figure out what the problem is.

This is the code I used for faceting graphics.

```
ggplot(exampledata, aes(x=code, y=cases,fill=sex))+
facet_wrap(~areas, norw = 2, scales = "free")+
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(exampledata, aes(x=code_sec %>% forcats::fct_reorder(code), y= cases, fill=sex))+
  facet_wrap(~areas, nrow = 2, scales = "free") +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", color = "black", fill = NA, 
           aes(group = sex, y = freq)) +
  labs(title = "Cases in shaded areas, frequency in outlined bars", x = "code_sec")
```

[image]

---

source data:

```
exampledata <- tibble(areas = c("area A", "area A", "area A", "area A", "area A", 
                             "area A", "area A",   "area A", "area A", "area B", "area B", 
                             "area B", "area B", "area B", "area B", "area B", "area B", 
                             "area B", "area B"),
                   code = c("A", "D", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "A", "B", "E", "F", "G", "E", "F", "G", "E", "H", "F", "G"),
                   code_sec = c("CS", "FA", "IC", "MO", "CS", "FA", "IC", "CS", "IC",  "CSIC", "ICMO", "MOFA", "CSIC", "ICMO", "MOFA", "CSIC", "FAME", "ICMO","MOFA"),
                   sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male",   "Male",   "Male" ,  "Unk",    "Unk",    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male",   "Male",  "Male", "Unk",  "Unk", "Unk", "Unk"),
                   cases = c(5,1,  8,  1,  3,  1, 11,  2,  5, 22,  5,  2, 17,  
                             6, 1, 13,  1, 4, 1),
                   freq = c(3,  6,  6,  3,  3, 2,  5,  4,  2,  9, 13,
                            9, 10,  4,  4, 11,  4,  3,  2))
```